# Mudar cor de fundo quando digitar uma cor através do v-bind

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Eu estou assistindo uma video aula de VueJS e não entendi a ligação do CSS com a classe e o como o fundo fica azul ou roxo de acordo com o que é digitado.

Exemplo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myClass: '',
  },     
});
```

```css
.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
    
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-on:input="myClass = $event.target.value">
  <p v-bind:class="myClass"> Classe CSS: {{ myClass }} </p>
</div>
```

Onde está a ligação que faz o VueJS saber sobre a cor de fundo? Pois no CSS não tem nenhuma classe `myClass`, ou algo que faça alguma ligação com o código.

Ex de como fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ao digitar no input, ele faz a ligação `myClass = $event.target.value`, transferindo o valor `purple` por exemplo para a variável `myClass`. Logo abaixo, ele utiliza o `v-bind:class`para atribuir uma classe ao `p`, nesse caso a class `purple` (valor de myClass), que está definido no CSS.

Comment: Tenta assim: `<input type="text" v-model="myClass">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repare que você está construindo uma nova instância de Vue:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myClass: '',
  }  
});
```

Observe que a variável `myClass` é iniciada como uma string vazia. Agora repare, no seu template, o seguinte:

```
<input type="text" v-on:input="myClass = $event.target.value">
```

A diretiva [`v-on`](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) é utilizada para ligar algum evento ao elemento em questão. No caso, com `v-on:input`, o Vue escutará por eventos [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/input) e, quando emitidos, executará a instrução indicada.

No caso, sempre que o evento `input` for emitido pelo usuário, você instruiu que o Vue execute este código: `myClass = $event.target.value`, que basicamente atribui à variável `myClass` (que definiu-se na criação do componente) o valor digitado pelo usuário.

Agora, indo para esta parte:

```
<p v-bind:class="myClass"> ... </p>
```

A diretiva [`v-bind`](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) é utilizada para atribuir o valor de alguma variável a algum atributo HTML, dinamicamente. Desse modo, com `v-bind:class`, você sempre mudará a classe do elemento `<p>` em resposta ao evento `input` do usuário (que muda a variável `myClass`.

No seu exemplo, o Vue não tem noção nenhuma da cor de fundo do elemento. Ele só "sabe" da classe que está sendo aplicada. A única parte da sua aplicação que realmente "sabe" da cor de fundo é o CSS.

Repare que você define, na sua folha de estilos, duas classes com duas respectivas cores de fundo. Sempre que o Vue.js (em resposta ao evento `input` do usuário) atribui uma das duas classes definidas no elemento, o CSS automaticamente irá aplicar os estilos definidos.

De modo geral, o CSS é "reativo" automaticamente. Sempre que uma classe é alterada ou removida (pelo JavaScript, por exemplo), o *browser* já entende que precisa refazer as estilizações, de modo que o CSS é aplicado automaticamente, sem a necessidade de intervenções de *frameworks* ou *bibliotecas*.